# Printing out an input range from a 2D Array

Tags: arrays, 2d

i need to input a range to print from, so eg: postcode 7003-7300.
I have sorted out the blocks of code to handle the input ranges, now just need to compare it with the array elements and print out accordingly. To do that do I need to convert the integer inputs to strings? Arrays are the bane of my life I have always struggled to understand how they work lol. any help is much appreciated.

example code of asking for firstpostcode value input.

```
    printf("Enter number of first postcode to display through ranges [7000-7470]:");

    while (scanf_s(" %d", &Firstcode) != 1)
    {
        // Tell the user that the entry was invalid
        printf("Invalid Entry\n");
        // Asterisk * tells scanf to read and ignore the value
        scanf_s("%*s");
    }

    if ((Firstcode >= 7000) && (Firstcode < 7470))
    {
        printf("Displaying from postcode %d \n", Firstcode);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("...Input outside boundaries: Postcode 7000 assumed...\n");
        Firstcode = 7000;
        printf("Displaying from postcode %d \n", Firstcode);
    }
```

2D array of post codes with elements being strings:
    char *postcodes[613][2] = 
    {

```
{ "7000", "Glebe" },
{ "7000", "Hobart" },
{ "7000", "Mount Stuart" },
{ "7000", "North Hobart" },
{ "7000", "West Hobart" },
{ "7001", "Hobart" },
{ "7002", "North Hobart" },
...
```

here is my incompleted loop after getting a correct input value for both first and last postcodes:

```
if ((Lastcode > Firstcode) && (Lastcode <= 7470))
    {
        printf("Displaying Postcodes %d to %d:\n", Firstcode, Lastcode);

        for (i = 0; i < 613; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {

                printf("%s\t", postcodes[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BIG 2D Array not printing out fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089452/big-2d-array-not-printing-out-fully)